# An idiom describing surprise over a lack in abundance of things

Tags: phrase-request

What idiom in English would describe the speaker's surprise over the fact that there was still some lack in an abundance of things?

In the quote below this expression must be substituted for the words "What on earth is his lack?!?!"

> Did you hear the news? Jefferson was trying to commit suicide last
>   night. **What on earth is his lack?!** He has everything: nice job, beautiful wife, kids,
>   a house, a car.

Comment: "What on earth is he lacking?"

Comment: Did you hear the news? Jefferson was trying to commit suicide last night. **What's wrong with this guy?** / **What's his problem?** He's got everything in life: nice job, beautiful wife with beautiful kids, a house and a car.

Comment: **commit suicide** is idiomatic, not **commit *a* suicide**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a context like this, I'd probably use "what more could he want?"

> He always seems unhappy, but I don't know why. He has a great job, beautiful family, and lives in a nice neighborhood. **What more could he want?**

"What more could he ask for?" could also work.

I definitely wouldn't use this in the context of suicide, though, because it sounds somewhat insensitive. It suggests that material possessions and external emotions are the only things that should factor into someone contemplation of suicide.

Comment: I like “What more could he ask for?” even better than “What more could he want?” I think “What more could he want?” suggests a little bit of whininess, but “What more could he ask for?” suggests that good fortune has smiled on the person.